# django-allauth is not working with Apache2+

Tags: python, django, apache, wsgi, django-allauth

I am using Django 1.8 on Python 3.6 with virtualenv, trying to integrate Google login with Django-allauth 0.23.0.it is working fine fine on python3 server (`python3 manage.py runserver`) but gives below error on production server (Apache2+wsgi)

```
Social Network Login Failure
An error occurred while attempting to login via your social network account.
Code: unknown, Error: Error retrieving access token: b'{\n "error": "invalid_scope",\n "error_description": "Some requested scopes were invalid. {valid\\u003d[https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email, openid], invalid\\u003d[https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email, https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile]}",\n "error_uri": "http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html"\n}'
```

The installed apps are given below

```
asgiref==3.2.3
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
confusable-homoglyphs==3.2.0
defusedxml==0.6.0
Django==1.8
django-allauth==0.23.0
django-crispy-forms==1.8.1
django-registration==2.0
idna==2.9
mysqlclient==1.4.6
oauthlib==3.1.0
python3-openid==3.1.0
pytz==2019.3
requests==2.23.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
urllib3==1.25.8
```

the setting.py file included below

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    #django apps
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #third party apps
    'crispy_forms',
    'registration',
    # 'custom_user',
    #my app
    # 'login',
    'newsletter',
    'accounts',

    # #social login
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'accounts.backends.EmailBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
    # 'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
]
# AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User'
# AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'custom_user.EmailUser'

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'tryDjango18.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'tryDjango18.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
     #'default': {
     #    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
     #    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
     #}
     'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '******',
        'USER': '*****',
        'PASSWORD': '****',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}


SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'profile',
            'email',
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'access_type': 'online',
        }
    }
}
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD='username_email' 
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True 
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True 
# Internationalization
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I fixed 
by  adding  *`ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL = "https"`* in my settings.py file